# Check if an array includes some special characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-formulas

I am trying to check if a password string contains some special characters.
I am trying to implement that with the following code:

```js
const passwordArr = "A1b2c3d4e5!@#".split("");
const specialChar = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some((letter) => {
  specialChar.includes(letter);
});
```

However, hasSpecLet returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `return` statement in the function you're passing to `some()`:

```
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some((letter) => {
  return specialChar.includes(letter);
});
```

Or just use a terser version (without the curly braces):

```
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some(letter => specialChar.includes(letter));
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: ahh I see - thanks. Does it mean that if I am going to use a return block, I must have a return keyword?

Comment: @EddieLam, If you're not using a *function expression* (that is, a one-line expression) you need to explicitly `return` the value

Answer (score 1):

whenever you are using `{ }` inside an arrow function you have to use `return` keyword O.W. values are returned by default.

```js
const passwordArr = "A1b2c3d4e5!@#".split("");
const specialChar = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some((letter) => {
   return specialChar.includes(letter);
});
console.log(hasSpecLet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` since the arrow function uses curly braces:

```js
const passwordArr = "A1b2c3d4e5!@#".split("");
const specialChar = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some((letter) => {
  return specialChar.includes(letter);
});
console.log(hasSpecLet);
```

Or do the following:

```js
const passwordArr = "A1b2c3d4e5!@#".split("");
const specialChar = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some((letter) => 
  specialChar.includes(letter)
);
console.log(hasSpecLet);
```

Answer (score 0):

This small change will make it work -

```js
const passwordArr = "A1b2c3d4e5!@#".split("");
const specialChar = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.some((letter) => 
  specialChar.includes(letter)
);

console.log(hasSpecLet)
```

The above change will make sure that the value processed by - `specialChar.includes(letter)` gets returned and used in the parent function to give the final result.

In your case, none of the letters returned a true value and hence you would have got false in every case

Answer (score 0):

Using some() and include()

```
const hasSpecLet  = passwordArr.some((letter) => specialChar.includes(letter))
```

Using intersection

```
const hasSpecLet = passwordArr.filter(value => specialChar.split('').includes(value)).length !== 0
```